# R: reproducing R hurdle regression summary table into latex output

Tags: r

I have been performing the hurdle regression (from: `library(pscl)`, using the command `summary(hurdle(y~x))`) for my supervisor and now I am trying to make the hurdle regression summary output into a latex table. However for some reason none of the usual tricks work - `xtable()`, `regtex()`, `latextable()` all refuses to convert the summary table into a latex output. I even tried `stargazer()` but of course the answer was no. Is there anyway I can convert the hurdle regression summary table into a latex output? I am not comfortable with LaTex and making one from the scratch would be really painful!

EDIT: What is remarkable about this problem is that `stargazer` and `texreg` both (the latter is more reasonable to me cause it gives both parts of the  model) give output on the console but throw an error in knitr documents.

Comment: did you try just latex() in Hmisc?

Comment: yup. not working....:(

Comment: `latextable()` throws me the following error: `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: `latex()` from `Hmisc` gives me the following error: `Error in as.character(string) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example which creates your model object. ``texreg`` should be able to handle hurdle models. If it doesn't, we need to examine the structure of your hurdle model object.